# Dependency resolution error for com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zza

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, google-play-services

I am getting the following error in Android Studio 3.6.1 when building:

Android Studio just suggested to update firebase and I did.

```
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzb found in modules jetified-play-services-base-11.6.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.6.0) and jetified-play-services-basement-17.2.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:17.2.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzc found in modules jetified-play-services-base-11.6.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.6.0) and jetified-play-services-basement-17.2.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:17.2.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zzd found in modules jetified-play-services-base-11.6.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.6.0) and jetified-play-services-basement-17.2.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:17.2.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.common.api.zza found in modules jetified-play-services-base-11.6.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.6.0) and jetified-play-services-basement-17.2.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:17.2.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.common.api.zzb found in modules jetified-play-services-base-11.6.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.6.0) and jetified-play-services-basement-17.2.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:17.2.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzb found in modules jetified-play-services-base-11.6.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.6.0) and jetified-play-services-basement-17.2.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:17.2.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzr found in modules jetified-play-services-base-11.6.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.6.0) and jetified-play-services-basement-17.2.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:17.2.0)
Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzs found in modules jetified-play-services-base-11.6.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.6.0) and jetified-play-services-basement-17.2.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:17.2.0)
Go to the documentation to learn how to Fix dependency resolution errors.
```

I am using gradle-5.6.4

I added this to my build.gradle as suggested by some other thread, but was unsuccessful:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:17.2.0'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Added an exception to all my dependencies:

```
implementation ('com.some.dependency:x.x.x') {
        transitive = true
        exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'
}
```

Then removed it one by one from all dependencies until I found the culprit package that was using the outdated 'com.google.android.gms'.